# Linux uboot tftp - serverip constantly resets to my router's ip address

Tags: linux, kernel, u-boot, tftp, som

The setup: I have an i.mx53 SOM connected to a switch, which is connected to a router. My main Windows computer is also connected to the switch. The Windows computer is running a VMWare Ubuntu 12.04, where I develop my code for the i.mx53.

The issue: I can't seem to get uboot to boot over tftp. The tftp server is running on the Ubuntu OS and is working correctly. I have tested sending files back and forth (good). However, every time I set the SOM's serverip= to the Ubuntu computer's IP address (where the kernel/rootfs are stored), the serverip switches to my router's IP address and it wont connect

Comment: Solution: ah I finally figured it out. "setenv dhcp=off" and then you have to do "run bootcmd"